# Number of increasing $n \times m$ matrices over $\{0,1\}$

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, combinations

Define an $n \times m$ matrix $M$ over $\{0,1\}$ to be *increasing* if for all $1 \leq i < j \leq n$:

- the number of $1$ in the $i$-th line $M_i$ of $M$ is less than the number of $1$ in the $j$-th line $M_j$
- if $M_i$ and $M_j$ have the same numbers of $1$, then $M_i \leq M_j$ where $\leq$ is the lexicographic order over $\{0,1\}^m$.

Example of a $7 \times 3$ increasing matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 1 \\
  1 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

It is easy to see that the number of $n \times m$ increasing matrices is

$$\sum_{i_0 + \dots + i_m = n} \left\{i_0,\binom{m}{0}\right\} \cdot \left\{i_1,\binom{m}{1}\right\} \cdots \left\{i_m,\binom{m}{m}\right\}$$
where $\{a,b\} = \binom{a+b-1}{b-1}$ is the number of [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $a$ into $b$ parts.

I would like to obtain upper bounds on this quantity. I think of $m$ mostly as a small number compared to $n$. I can prove (using $\{a,b\} \leq (a+b)^{b-1}$ and other weak bounds) that it is less than $(n + 2^m)^{2^m}$, which is small compared to the total number $2^{n \cdot m}$ of $\{0,1\}$ matrices if $n >> m$. However, I suspect that the exponent could by greatly improved. Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Isn't it just $\binom{2^m}{n}$? You have a total order on $\{0,1\}^m$, and you're effectively counting sets of $n$ elements. Then an upper bound would be $2^{mn}/n!$.

Comment: No because you can take several times the same element. If wouldn't make sense to have $\binom{2^m}{n}$ possibilities, since it is not defined for $n > 2^m$.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. In that case it's $\binom{2^m+n-1}{n}$, the number of non-decreasing sequences of $n$ elements from a totally ordered set of order $2^m$.

Comment: Oh yes, that's super easy! It's just the number of weak compositions of $2^m$ in $n$ parts. Thank you!

Comment: So isn't it $\binom{2^m + n - 1}{n - 1}$ instead?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the terminology of weak compositions, I would see it as a multiset. The number of multisets of cardinality $n$ taken from a set of order $2^m$ is $\binom{2^m+n-1}{n}$ - see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets